# Mybatis ResultHandler with spring boot could not run

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, mybatis

I have a query with a big result, so that I follow document from MyBatis using ResultHandler for handle result

Because I just want to put all result to a Map, so that ResultHandler may help me.

```
@Mapper
Interface ObjRepository {
  @Result(value = {....})
  @Select("SELECT .... FROM .... 
          JOIN .... JOIN ... WHERE country = #{country} ...")
  Void consumeResult(@Parram('country') String country, ResultHanlder<MyObjDto> handle)
}
```

The Spring boot auto create a ObjRepository instance for me and I use it in other class

```
@Sfl4j
@Service
public class MyService {
  private Map<Long, MyObjDto> map = new HashMap();

  @Autowired ObjRepository objRepository;

  @PostConstruct
  public init() {
    Log.info("start loading");
    objReposity.consumeResult("US", dto -> map.put(dto.getId(), dto)); 
    Log.info("finish");
  }

}
```

My problem is when I start Spring boot application, it will stuck in function `consumeResult` and never finish this fuction.

I tried to find document from MyBatis but found nothing. Am I config wrong something? I'm using PostgreSql for current project

Comment: There seems to be a typo (`@Result` -> `@Results`), but other than that, it looks OK. Try reproducing the issue with a minimum project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues). If you could share it on GitHub, I would look into it. If it's difficult, enable logging and find out where exactly it gets stuck (query, mapping result, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a deeper look, I have found some issues.

- Return type must be `void` not `Void`.
- The statement must have `@ResultMap` or `@ResultType`. `@Result` is not supported, it seems [1].
- The parameter passed to `ResultHandler#handleResult()` is `ResultContext`, so you need to call `getResultObject()` to get your DTO.

  ```java
  objReposity.consumeResult("US", resultContext -> {
    MyObjDto dto = resultContext.getResultObject();
    map.put(dto.getId(), dto);
  });
  ```

[1] Without looking into the implementation, supporting `@Results` may be possible, technically. You should create an enhancement request on the [tracker](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues).

---

Additional information that might be useful.

- There is a handy annotation `@MapKey` that achieves the same mapping without using `ResultHandler`, but it might not be the best solution when the query returns many rows.

  ```java
  @MapKey("id")
  @Results({@Result(), @Result(),...})
  @Select("SELECT .... FROM .... 
          JOIN .... JOIN ... WHERE country = #{country} ...")
  Map<Integer, MyObjDto> select(@Param('country') String country)
  ```
- Using `Cursor` could be more efficient when dealing with a large number of rows. Please see the [documentation](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html) for the details.